# Why can I not open some website with C# web browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, web

I'm trying to create a simple WPF window in C# with a web browser inside.
It works with some common website like Google or Youtube. However, there are some cases that errors occurs when I change the Source.
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEMNr.png)

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WEB0.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WEB0"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="VKP opens Website" Height="600" Width="1000" Background="Gray">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Source="https://pythonparts.allplan.com/" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

</Grid>
```

I don't how to solve this error or where it come from. So, I need some help here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I would suggest embedding the picture in the question directly instead of adding a link to it, and also write explicitly the link that you were trying to use that didn't work (I know it appears in the picture, but having it as text might help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you point the control to https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ you'll notice it gets reported as IE11, that's because WebBrowser uses an old ActiveX control. A lot of modern web sites simply don't support browsers that old.

If you want to embed Chromium then you'll need to look into one of the 3rd-party solutions for doing so. If your target OS supports Edge then you can instead simply replace WebBrowser with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) by installing `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` via NuGet and using the WPF control it provides:

```
<wv:WebView2 xmlns:wv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    Source="https://www.somewebsite.com/" />
```

Comment: Isn't WebView2 chromium based anyway?

Comment: Side note there is also GeckoFX if one wants to use embedded Firefox

Comment: @CaiusJard nope, [the one I linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) uses Edge.

Comment: And these days Edge is...

Comment: @CaiusJard gawd, total brain fart. I was thinking Chrome all along. In my defense, I've got the Rona atm and not thinking straight :D Thanks for pointing out my blunder.